# MongoDb aggregate pipeline with multiple groupings

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get my head around an aggregate pipeline in MongoDb with multiple groups.

I have the following data: https://gist.github.com/bomortensen/36e6b3fbc987a096be36a66bbfe30d82

Expected data would be: https://gist.github.com/bomortensen/7b220df1f1da83be838acfb2ed79a2ee (total quantity sum based on highest version, hourly)

I need to write a query which does the following:

1. Group the data by the field `MeterId` to get unique meter groups.
2. In each group I then need to group by the `StartDate`'s year, month, day and hour since all objects `StartDate` is stored as quarters, but I need to aggregate them into whole hours.

   3. Finally, I need to only get the highest version from the `Versions` array by `VersionNumber`

I've tried the following query, but must admit I'm stuck:

```
mycollection.aggregate([        
    { $group: { 
            _id : { ediel: "$_id.MeterId", start: "$_id.StartDate" },
            versions: { $push: "$Versions" }            
        } 
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$versions" } },
    { $group: {
            _id: {
                hour: { $hour: "$_id.start.DateTime" },
                key: "$_id"                                
            },              
            quantitySum: { $sum: "$Versions.Quantity" }          
         } 
    },
    { $sort: { "_id.hour": -1 } }
]);
```

Does anyone know how I should do this? :-)

Comment: add the expected output please

Comment: Added expected output to my post, @Veeram :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give :

- 1 `$project` : get `$hour` from date, create a `maxVersion` field per record
- 1 `$unwind` to remove the `Versions` array
- 1 `$project` to add a `keep` field that will contain a boolean to check if the record should be kept or not
- 1 `$match` that match only higher version number eg `keep == true`
- 1 `$group` that group by id/hour and sum the quantity
- 1 `$project` to set up your required format

Query is :

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        Versions: 1,
        hour: {
            "$hour": "$_id.StartDate"
        },
        maxVersion: { $max: "$Versions.VersionNumber" }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Versions"
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        Versions: 1,
        hour: 1,
        maxVersion: 1,
        keep: { $eq: ["$Versions.VersionNumber", "$maxVersion"] }
    }
}, {
    $match: { "keep": true }

}, {
    $group: {
        _id: { _id: "$_id.MeterId", hour: "$hour" },
        StartDate: { $first: "$_id.StartDate" },
        QuantitySum: { $sum: "$Versions.Quantity" }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: { _id: "$_id._id", StartDate: "$StartDate" },
        hour: "$_id.hour",
        QuantitySum: 1
    }
}])
```

In your example output you take into account only the first higher versionNumber, You have `{ "VersionNumber" : 2, "Quantity" : 7.5 }` and `{ "VersionNumber" : 2, "Quantity" : 8.4 }` for hour `2` and id `1234` but you only take `{ "VersionNumber" : 2, "Quantity" : 7.5 }`

I dont know if this is intended or not but in this case you want to take only the first MaxVersion number. After the `$match`, I added :

- 1 `$group` that push versions previously filter in an array
- 1 `$project` that `$slice` this array to take only the first element
- 1 `$unwind` to remove this array (which contains only one elemement)

The query that match your output is :

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        Versions: 1,
        hour: {
            "$hour": "$_id.StartDate"
        },
        maxVersion: { $max: "$Versions.VersionNumber" }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Versions"
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        Versions: 1,
        hour: 1,
        maxVersion: 1,
        keep: { $eq: ["$Versions.VersionNumber", "$maxVersion"] }
    }
}, {
    $match: { "keep": true }

}, {
    $group: {
        _id: { _id: "$_id.MeterId", StartDate: "$_id.StartDate" },
        Versions: { $push: "$Versions" },
        hour: { "$first": "$hour" }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        hour: 1,
        Versions: { $slice: ["$Versions", 1] }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$Versions"
}, {
    $sort: {
        _id: 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: { _id: "$_id._id", hour: "$hour" },
        StartDate: { $first: "$_id.StartDate" },
        QuantitySum: { $sum: "$Versions.Quantity" }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: { _id: "$MeterId._id", StartDate: "$StartDate" },
        Hour: "$_id.hour",
        QuantitySum: 1
    }
}])
```

Output is :

```
{ "_id" : { "MeterId" : "4567", "StartDate" : ISODate("2016-09-20T03:00:00Z") }, "QuantitySum" : 25.9, "Hour" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "MeterId" : "4567", "StartDate" : ISODate("2016-09-20T02:00:00Z") }, "QuantitySum" : 25.9, "Hour" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "MeterId" : "1234", "StartDate" : ISODate("2016-09-20T03:00:00Z") }, "QuantitySum" : 25.9, "Hour" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "MeterId" : "1234", "StartDate" : ISODate("2016-09-20T02:00:00Z") }, "QuantitySum" : 25.9, "Hour" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just dont find a straight forward way to round the hour. You can try the following. You will unwind the versions, so you can apply the grouping to collect the max version, push the versions for the next step, which is to project to filter the matching records with max version and final project to sum the max versions quantity. Right now start dt is the min from the group. You should be fine as long as you have versions at the top of the hour.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$Versions"
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            MeterId: "$_id.MeterId",
            start: {
                $hour: "$_id.StartDate"
            }
        },
        startDate: {
            $min: "$_id.StartDate"
        },
        maxVersion: {
            $max: "$Versions.VersionNumber"
        },
        Versions: {
            $push: "$Versions"
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "_id.start": -1
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: {
            MeterId: "$_id.MeterId",
            StartDate: "$startDate"
        },
        hour: "$_id.start",
        Versions: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$Versions",
                as: "version",
                cond: {
                    $eq: ["$maxVersion", "$$version.VersionNumber"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        hour: 1,
        QuantitySum: {
            $sum: "$Versions.Quantity"
        }
    }
}]);
```

Sample Output

```
{
    "_id": {
        "MeterId": "1234",
        "StartDate": ISODate("2016-09-20T02:00:00Z")
    },
    "QuantitySum": 15,
    "hour": 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, Veeram! Greatly appreciated :-) It all makes sence, but one question remains: what if I only want to get the quantity sum from only the highest version in the `Versions` array?